# Enable/ disable button not working when ttk is used

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, ttk

ttk is used for all the buttons. "disable" button works when "Button1" and "Button2" are in tk but it does not work when ttk is used. How can this be solved for the code?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

fenster = tk.Tk()
fenster.title("Window")

canvas = tk.Canvas(fenster,bg="white",width=700, height=410, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

def switch1():
    if b1["state"] == "normal":
        b1["state"] = "disabled"
    else:
        b1["state"] = "normal"

def switch2():
    if b3["state"] == "normal":
        b3["state"] = "disabled"
    else:
        b3["state"] = "normal"

#--Buttons
b1 = ttk.Button(canvas, text="Button1")  #works when tk is used
canvas.create_window(5, 5, window=b1, anchor=tk.NW)

b3 = ttk.Button(canvas, text="Button2") #works when tk is used
canvas.create_window(5, 100, window=b3, anchor=tk.NW)

b2 = ttk.Button(canvas, text="disable", command=switch1)
canvas.create_window(100, 5, window=b2, anchor=tk.NW)

b4 = ttk.Button(canvas, text="disable", command=switch2)
canvas.create_window(100, 100, window=b4, anchor=tk.NW)

fenster.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `b1.state(('!disabled' if 'disabled' in b1.state() else 'disabled',))` in `switch1()`.  Similar applies to `switch2()`.

Comment: @stovfl I got it. Thanks